# Shishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One shekel = 160 grains of silver - Rambam, Shekalim, 1:5

Avraham was 160 yrs old when Yaakov was born - Midrash Bereishis 25

Answer (score 4):

160 were the millions of *Sh'lomo*'s horses (*Sanhedrin* 21:2).

Answer (score 3):

In his introduction to the Maharil's responsa (preserved in a couple of manuscripts, and printed in the Mechon Yerushalayim edition), the compiler, R' Zalman of St. Goar, bemoans the fact that he was able to gather only 160 of these responsa for publication. (The rest were found in manuscript and published by Mechon Yerushalayim.)

Answer (score 2):

> In the year 3591 from creation (169
>   BCE), **160 years** after the
>   Greeks conquered Eretz Yisrael,
>   Antiochus IV (Epiphanes) began
>   oppressing the Jews.  Under his rule,
>   the Greeks despoiled the holy vessels
>   of the Temple, breached the walls of
>   Jerusalem, murdered thousands of Jews,
>   and enslaved many others.

http://www.israelnationalnews.com/Articles/Article.aspx/9842

Comment: The version I now see at that page says "In the year 3591 from creation (169 BCE), around 160 years after...".

Answer (score 1):

עץ = 160 appropiate as we are entering the month of Shevat

קין ,כסף, עיניך = 160,

Answer (score 1):

160 is [supposedly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_of_Ancona) the number of Jews [Jacob d'Ancona found](http://books.google.com/books?id=3XxMIPQlxY0C&pg=PA106&dq=sixty) in Ceylon.